# How can I right align text in a table using SwissQRBill?

Tags: typescript, pdfkit, swissqrbill

I am drawing PDF content using SwissQRBill which is an extension of PDFKit. I use TypeScript. SwissQRBill gives the option to create tables. However, I can't figure out how to right-align the text in a specific column. I would like to right-align all values in the column "Price". This is the first row in my table.

```
{
  fillColor: '#ECF0F1',
  columns: [
    {
      text: 'Article',
      width: mm2pt(15),
    },
    {
      text: 'Price',
    },
  ],
};
```

I searched the web, read the documentation of SwissQRBill and PDFKit and asked ChatGPT but I can't find the answer to my question.

This is the package I am using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/swissqrbill

This is the documentation of SwissQRBill: https://github.com/schoero/SwissQRBill/blob/master/doc/api.md#addtabletable

How can I right-align the text in specific columns in my table using SwissQRBill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. the solution can be found in the documentation:

https://github.com/schoero/SwissQRBill/blob/master/doc/api.md#addtabletable

and

https://pdfkit.org/docs/text.html#text_styling

```
{
  fillColor: '#ECF0F1',
  columns: [
    {
      text: 'Article',
      width: mm2pt(15),
    },
    {
      text: 'Price',
      textOptions: {align: 'right'},
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The creator of the package answered the question on GitHub.

https://github.com/schoero/SwissQRBill/issues/413

> You can use `textOptions: { align: "right" }` for that.
>
> However, I noticed that there is an error in the calculation of the column width, where the padding is not subtracted. So by default, the text overflows the column by the width of the padding, which is `5` by default.
>
> As a workaround, you can set the `left` padding to a negative number of the padding that you actually want for that column. If you didn't set a padding manually, this would be `padding: [undefined, undefined, undefined, -5]`.
>
> ```
> {
>   rows: [
>     {
>       fillColor: '#ECF0F1',
>       columns: [
>         {
>           text: 'Product',
>           width: mm2pt(15),
>         },
>         {
>           text: 'Price',
>           textOptions: { align: "right" },
>           padding: [undefined, undefined, undefined, -5]
>         },
>       ],
>     }
>   ]
> };
> ```
>
> Here are two images to illustrate what i mean:
>
> Without the workaround:
>
> With negative padding:
>
> Unfortunately I don't wan't to publish a fix for this issue, because at this point, it would most certainly be a breaking change for some users who have already worked around this issue. And for the next major release, this is already fixed.